# Сформировать вектор из элементов массива

Tags: c, массивы, циклы, вектор

Дано задание:
**Для квадратной матрицы размера n*n подсчитать среднее арифметическое
элементов каждого столбца, исключая элемент на главной диагонали, и сформировать из них вектор. Найти минимальный элемент этого вектора.**
(Размерность массивов вводит пользователь, затем пользователь также заполняет массив значениями. Массив статический).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"RUSSIAN");
    printf("\tСоздание массива размером n*n. Введите значение n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arr[n][n];
    printf("\n\tВведите значения массива:");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("\nВведите %d-ю строку %d-й столбец: ", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n\tМассив:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("\t%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

С созданием и заполнением массива у меня проблем нет.

```
    double a, e, k;
    double vec[n];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) // среднее арифметическое по столбцам
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (i = j) // исключая элемент на главной диагонали
                a += 0; 
            else
                a += arr[i][j]; // сумма элементов столбца
        }
        e = a / n; // среднее арифметическое столбца
        vec[j] = e;
    }
    printf("\n\tВектор:");
    k = vec[0];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        printf("\t%.2f ", vec[j]);
        if (k > vec[j]) // поиск минимального элемента вектора
            k = vec[j];
    }
    printf("\n\tМинимальный элемент вектора = ");
    printf("%.2f", k);
```

Ну и дальше у меня ничего не выводит, полагаю что проблема в цикле (может вообще не правильно добавляю элементы в вектор). Разобраться не могу. Помогите

Comment: В строчке `if(i = j) a += 0;` должно быть `if(i == j) a += 0;` а лучше эти 4 строчки поменять на `if(i != j) a += arr[i][j];`

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!

Comment: Я тогда выложу ответ и буду благодарен если вы его примите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В двойном цикле, где вы считаете сумму столбика у вас ошибка в строчке:

```
if(i = j) a += 0;
```

Должно быть вот так:

```
if(i == j) a += 0;
```

А лучше заменить:

```
if (i = j)
    a += 0; 
else
    a += arr[i][j];
```

На:

```
if(i != j) a += arr[i][j];
```